# When compiling, can I use a file for ./configure options?

Tags: compiling, configure, options

Building some software from source and there are a lot of configure switches.

`./configure --enable-ftp --with-gettext ...`

I have all the switches I want in a text file separated by new lines, e.g.:

```
--enable-ftp
--with-gettext
etc...
```

Is there a way I can pass the text file as an argument to configure to set the options?  Or some other way to cut and paste the options that I have?

**EDIT**

I am using `$HOME` variable in my switches so any solution should accommodate that.

Comment: Sure: `./configure \`cat file\` `.  You might also want to look at [Comfigure](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Comfigure), it basically remembers `configure` options from previous runs for the same package.

Comment: If you have already done the hard part of putting all the switches in a text file, just make it an executable shell script by adding a shebang line and run that.

Comment: @Munir From the question: _... separated by new lines ..._

Comment: @SatoKatsura add a \ at the end of the lines...I mean you are going through the pain of typing out all the switches in a file, why not just make that an executable.

Comment: @SatoKatsura if this is an answer I hope you make it an official answer because I like to see how the community votes for the preferred answer so I can learn the recommended way to do it and the pros/cons of each way

Comment: Rest assured, it won't win any popularity contest, not among people who think of themselves as being able to teach others how to write scripts. :) Anyway, my real answer was to point you to Comfigure.  Very useful tool.

Comment: @don_crissti: bash.  Yes it appears I have that

Answer (score 2):

To expand `$HOME` in your file you could use `envsubst` first (be aware this will expand any env variable). Then you could read the result into an array e.g. with `zsh`

```
args=(${(f)"$(< <(envsubst <infile))"})
```

or with `bash`

```
readarray -t args < <(envsubst <infile)
```

and then run

```
./configure "${args[@]}"
```

Alternatively, you could use `tr` to format the result as a single line of options preceded by `./configure`, and pipe that to `sh`:

```
{ printf %s './configure '; tr '\n' ' ' <infile; } | sh
```

Comment: `./configure \`cat file\`` works as well, I've been doing that forever. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura - it works in this case but I _never_ use `command \`cat file\``

Comment: I'm using that a lot when I'm editing the names of my music collection.  There, it's quite useful.  Just about anywhere else, it's dangerous.

Comment: @don_crissti what's wrong with cat file here?

Comment: @User One side-effect of `cat` is that the shell will expand things like `*` or `$VAR` in your file, while my `xargs` approach will not. That could be a positive or a negative.

Comment: @don_crissti: I guess I meant in the general case since you said "never" emphasized

Comment: @User - then why does your question end in _"here"_ ? :)  For the general case, the `cat squeeze` thingie will be subject to word splitting and that may have some undesired effects...

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use `xargs`, which turns whitespace-separated strings on stdin into command-line arguments.  If your file is called `switches`, this would look like:

```
xargs ./configure < switches
```

This will not expand things like `*` or `$VAR`.  If (as in your edit) you want these to be expanded, then there are a few approaches. We can simply create a command and pass it to `sh`:

```
xargs printf '%s ' ./configure < switches | sh
```

Or, if you have `envsubst`, this will expand variables (like `${HOME}`) but not file globs (`*`):

```
envsubst < switches | xargs ./configure
```